# Emails are not validating with filter_var

Tags: php, validation, email, filter-var

I'm making now registration for my site. I have made validation.php file in which i have all functions that are validating my data. Email is validated like this:

```
if (filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) {
    $allChecked = false;
    $_SESSION['emailError'] = "Your email has to be valid.";
}
```

But when i click on button (in registration form) when email is invalid (random letters) is gets through validation like the email is okay. So how i have to this so the email gets properly validated.
Thanks for every answer

Comment: can you show an example of an invalid email that passes?

Comment: invalid email is any random letters combined e.g. dd, wiabd, adad, iuhtst.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Check out http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb12f32cc9b613c13c10fc61efaf295bab5f1ca2

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below.

It will allow good email but will prevent in valid email

```
        $email= 'nancy@gmai';  // bad email
    /*
    $email= 'nancy@gmail.com';  //good email
    */
        $em= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if (!$em){
        echo "Email Address is Invalid";
 //$_SESSION['emailError'] = "Your email has to be valid.";

        exit();
        }
```